# Swift - Compare array with same array in swift and if find similar values then add or combine or sum values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am working on the project where I have an array for class objects. I want to iterate each object and see if there exist duplicate values in the array then add or sum values into one.

Example:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

internal var displays: Int?
internal var id: String?
}
```

I have an array of SomeClass, when id is the same then add values of displays into one.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you tried and explain what went wrong

Comment: Have a look at `NSCountedSet`

Comment: I was trying with For loop but it i didn't work out. I am trying with Map, Filter and reduce but so far it didn't work out as well. I spent couple hours to get the result but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

This code should work:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

    var displays: Int
    var id: String

    init(_ id: String, _ displays: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.displays = displays
    }
}


//Example of filtering

let array = [
    SomeClass("1", 1),
    SomeClass("3", 3),
    SomeClass("4", 7),
    SomeClass("8", 8),
    SomeClass("2", 3),
    SomeClass("7", 2),
    SomeClass("5", 5),
    SomeClass("1", 1),
    SomeClass("3", 4),
    SomeClass("2", 2),
    SomeClass("7", 5),
    SomeClass("6", 8)
]

var resultDictionary: [String : Int] = [:]

for element in array {
    let lastDisplays = resultDictionary[element.id] ?? 0 //if object with this id is first time counted, the resultDictionary[element.id] will return nil and then lastDisplays will be equal to 0

    resultDictionary[element.id] = lastDisplays + element.displays
}

var result = resultDictionary.map { SomeClass($0.key, $0.value) }
```

In the end the `result` array will contain `SomeClass` objects with counted `displays`.

Because dictionary have only unique keys, we can use it for counting displays sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {
    internal var displays: Int?
    internal var id: String?

    init(displays: Int?, id: String?) {
        self.displays = displays
        self.id = id
    }
}

var array = [
    SomeClass(displays: 2, id: "123"),
    SomeClass(displays: 3, id: "456"),
    SomeClass(displays: 4, id: "123"),
]

var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

for obj in array {
    if let id = obj.id, displays = obj.displays {
        let prevDisplays = counts[id] ?? 0
        counts[id] = prevDisplays + displays
    }
}

print(counts)
```

**EDIT:** If you would like to have more functional version of above, I can only come up with the following:

```
counts = array.reduce([String: Int]()) { dict, item in
    var dict = dict
    if let id = item.id, displays = item.displays {
        dict.updateValue((dict[id] ?? 0) + displays, forKey: id)
    }
    return dict
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me quickly try and give you heads up. I am wondering if we can do the same thing with Map, filter and reduce etc.